# Mysql Php combining 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql

basically in this web app i have an event module where user can create, edit and delete an event also can upload photo for that event. Other users either can involve in particular event by selecting `I'm in` button or just mentioning the event `Sound's Cool`.
For now there is 3 tables `event_photo` (user upload pic will be saved here), `event_in` and `event_cool`, now i need an event activity feed, for that i need to combine all 3 tables by grouping them as `photo`, `in` and `cool`. So i need suggestion whether to create a single table to list these activity or should i combine all the results in php. Previously i combine all 2 results in single table but now i want to try something different. There are the table structure.

event_photo table

```
id      photo_url      business_id     event_id         user_id    caption    added_date
1         1111             12             2                3       test1      20130209t1
2         1122             13             3                4       test2      20130209t4
3         1133             14             2                3       test3      20130209t2
```

event_in table

```
id  event_id    user_id    date_created
1         2                3       20130209t3
```

event_cool

```
id  event_id    user_id  date_created
1         2               4        20130209t5
2         3               3        20130209t6
```

Now the feed will be like this, based on `date_created desc` `t6 -> t1`

```
User_3 says cool for  Event_3
User_4 says cool for  Event_2
User_4 added photo for Event_3
User_3 added photo for Event_2
User_3 attending  Event_2
User_3 added photo for Event_2
User_3 added photo for Event_2
```

Now how the table should be design, i hope this is important questions as this can resolve many problems regarding activity feed.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to have your three tables and query them with something similar to:

```
  SELECT *
    FROM
         ( SELECT user_id, 
                  event_id, 
                  date_added as date_created,
                  'photo' as type
             FROM event_photo
            UNION
           SELECT user_id, 
                  event_id, 
                  date_created,
                  'event_in' as type
             FROM event_in
            UNION
           SELECT user_id, 
                  event_id, 
                  date_created,
                  'event_cool' as type
             FROM event_cool
         ) s
  ORDER BY date_created
```

To simplify your code, you could create a view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_ordered_actions AS
  SELECT *
    FROM
         ( SELECT user_id, 
                  event_id, 
                  date_added as date_created,
                  'photo' as type
             FROM event_photo
            UNION
           SELECT user_id, 
                  event_id, 
                  date_created,
                  'event_in' as type
             FROM event_in
            UNION
           SELECT user_id, 
                  event_id, 
                  date_created,
                  'event_cool' as type
             FROM event_cool
         ) s
  ORDER BY date_created;
```

Comment: What do you mean? The first version is just a query that you can execute from a MySQL client or from your PHP code. The second one must be executed on a MySQL client (as PHPMyAdmin) and then you'll be able to do something like: `SELECT * from v_ordered_actions WHERE ....`

Comment: yes i get the result but the result there is no mention whats the result row are for..? event_in,event_cool or add photo

Comment: You're right. I edited the response to add a "type" string that will inform of the record type

Answer (score 1):

You can use UNION of course: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html However, this is quite slow. Maybe better to create next table, like activity log, where to store just:

- entity_type (in/cool/photo)
- entity_id (id of row in target table)
- event_id
- user_id
- date

And select via this. When you have selected that, collect all IDs seperatelly for each target table, and get necessary info from that tables (if necessary) returned as indexed array. Foreach activity feed and assign correct data you need for it.

Hope this can help you.